# How to use original "break" in a loop when using pry-debugger

Tags: ruby, pry

How can I use `break` in a loop while using `pry-debugger` that has `break` function?

```
10.times do |i|
  break if i > 2
end
```

This code will fail with error `ArgumentError: Cannot identify arguments as breakpoint`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `break`, you could use `break()`. The parenthesis will help ruby distinguish between pry-debugger's `break`, and the ruby `break()` function. Your code would then look like this:

```
10.times do |i|
  break() if i > 2
end
```